# How to get a Java Program to email you?

Tags: java, email, localhost

I'm creating a program whereby I want email notifications when something happens, i.e

```
x=2.5

if(x>1.5)
{
//Send an email to myself with the variable x
}
```

And then have an email output of:

```
'x has a value of 2.5'
```

How do i do this? I've read around and read about using localhost, but the answer was not greta and I'm still unsure as on what to do

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you look at the JavaMail API, here's a simple [Java-Sending Email Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm) to get things moving quickly with your code.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [JavaMail](http://javamail.java.net/) API. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

See "Apache Commons Email" - it's a pretty easy-to-use Java email API.

[Here's a link to the documentation.](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/javadocs/api-release/index.html)

[Here's a link to examples of usage.](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/userguide.html)